# SQL: Subquery issue

Tags: sql, vertica

```
Table A
----------------
Date  index
------------------
2016-10-20   2.3
2016-10-21   2.8
-------      ---
-------      ---


Table B:
--------
Code Life_completed
A      5
b      6
```

Actual Query:

```
select *,(select sum(index) 
          from table1 
          where date between current_date +3 AND current_date
          ) as Index 
from table b
```

Expected Query:
Can we replace current_date +3 with `current_date +Life_completed`

We are using vertica database..

Please help here..

Comment: Please tag the database

Comment: Did you try replacing it? It should work (of course you have to switch the values used in between)

Comment: @dnoeth: Yes I tried..Getting Some error..Correlated subquery column in select/gby/oby not supported

Comment: In MySQL the below query works, you can try similar way. `select *,(select sum(A.index) 
          from A 
          where date between (current_date + B.life_completed) AND current_date
          ) as 'Index'
from B`

Answer (score 0):

This Correlated Subquery is the same as a Left Join plus sum:

```
select b.Code, b.Life_completed,
   sum(a.index) as Index 
from tableB b 
left join tableA as a 
  on a.date between current_date AND current_date + B.life_completed
```